# Error inflating Text Input Layout even though MaterialComponent style is used

Tags: android

I am trying to use TextInputLayout from Materials Components. Even tho my style is like this:
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"`, I am getting an error.

I have looked through all the similar questions on web(including stack overflow). All of them suggest to change the theme from appCompat to materialComponents, but i have already done that.

This the part of the XML that causes the error

```
      (line 34) <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_title"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

error itself:

```
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34 in com.example.happyplaces:layout/activity_add_happy_place: Binary XML file line #34 in com.example.happyplaces:layout/activity_add_happy_place: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
```

i have materialcomponents dependency in the build file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0-alpha03'
```

here is the full stack trace:

```
2022-08-15 10:08:31.489 16671-16671/com.example.happyplaces E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.happyplaces, PID: 16671
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.happyplaces/com.example.happyplaces.AddHappyPlaceActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34 in com.example.happyplaces:layout/activity_add_happy_place: Binary XML file line #34 in com.example.happyplaces:layout/activity_add_happy_place: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3410)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34 in com.example.happyplaces:layout/activity_add_happy_place: Binary XML file line #34 in com.example.happyplaces:layout/activity_add_happy_place: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34 in com.example.happyplaces:layout/activity_add_happy_place: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at com.example.happyplaces.databinding.ActivityAddHappyPlaceBinding.inflate(ActivityAddHappyPlaceBinding.java:104)
        at com.example.happyplaces.databinding.ActivityAddHappyPlaceBinding.inflate(ActivityAddHappyPlaceBinding.java:98)
        at com.example.happyplaces.AddHappyPlaceActivity.onCreate(AddHappyPlaceActivity.kt:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3410)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
2022-08-15 10:08:31.491 16671-16671/com.example.happyplaces E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:241)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:215)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:143)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:113)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:467)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:446)
            ... 31 more
```

```
i cant find out what causes the error here. Any help would be very appreciated.
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: `The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant)` - no it's clear that your app theme does not inherit one of `MaterialComponents` base themes

Answer (score 1):

The problem is I was still using AppCompat library for another style. That was the cause. It took me one day to figure out.